# How to scroll text smoothly using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to scroll a single line of text smooth as possible

My target device is a 1920 x 120 resolution with no input. (no keyboard or mouse). It has an Underpowered CPU.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>News</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $.get('data.txt', function(data) {
                    $('#text-file-container').html(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="content.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="scroll">
            <h1>
                <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="15" id="text-file-container"></marquee>
            </h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a JS library i found online but it was performing very poorly
I am open to suggestions

Comment: "1920 x 120"? Do you mean 1920x120**0**?

Comment: No 120px is what I mean. It's a thin and wide display

Comment: `marquee` is obsolete and should be avoided.

Comment: What's the modern equivalent?

Comment: The equivalent would be using CSS transitions and animations

Comment: I'm open to any suggestion about what you're talking about. Do you have any sample code to show this or a link with sample code on JSFiddle. I went online and tried a dozen examples with jQuery and marquee but they were not animating smooth at all. It was jumping or had other issues

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try using CSS animations and transitions instead a JavaScript library/plugin or `marquee` (that as mentioned on the comments, it is [obsolete and should be avoided](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0)).

One example of how it could be done with CSS and animations:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from { left: 100%;}
  to { left: -100%;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from { left: 100%;}
  to { left: -100%;}
}

#marquee { 
  color:red; 
  background:#f0f0f0;
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  line-height:120px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

#text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  font-size:30px;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="marquee">
 <div id="text">Your Text</div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the speed of the marquee by changing the value of the `animation-duration`. And you should modify the value of the `to` depending on the length of text.

---

Update after [comment from Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638465/how-to-scroll-text-smoothly-using-html5/32639529#comment85745569_32639529): the marquee failed when the text was larger than the space of the marquee. One solution would be to make blank space not wrap/break and animations that take into account the size of the text (using transforms and not only position to move the text):

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from { left:100%; transform: translate(0, 0); }
  to { left: -100%; transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from { left:100%; transform: translate(0, 0); }
  to { left: -100%; transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

.marquee { 
  color:red; 
  background:#f0f0f0;
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  line-height:120px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:120px;
  font-size:30px;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<p>Text Fits</p>
<div class="marquee">
 <div class="text">Text Here</div>
</div>

<p>Text overflows</p>
<div class="marquee">
 <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eget sem non lacus condimentum dictum quis id tortor.</div>
</div>
```

Then the movement is a bit choppy on my browser. I will look for a more *smooth* solution, but this would fix the text length issue.

Comment: correction: we need to increase the value of width: of #text to fit in a lengthier text. and it did work! Good job Alvaro!

Comment: how to make it as vertical scroll? i would like to get it as vertical scroll instead of horizontal

Comment: This is nice however it doesn't work with text string lengths that exceed the #marquee 's width.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for letting me know about that problem. I added a second version taking into account that, but it looks a bit choppy on my computer. I'll check if I can find a better CSS-only solution later.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hmm I ran the snippet here in both Safari and Chrome and I don't see any text in the "Text overflows" box at all.

Comment: @Jay what OS and browser version? I tested on Mac and iOS on Safari and Chrome and it seems to be ok.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Mac OS 10.11.6 Safari 11.03, Chrome 65.0.3325.162

Comment: @Jay Weird. I am running the same browser versions, but using macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: How do you compare HTML to AS3 in terms of scroll smosthness ? It's choppy on flash players with AS3, I am still searching for a solution

Comment: In the second example, instead of `left:-100%` it may be better as `left:0` because the animation ends when the text right border touches the marquee left border.